# How can I show extra info of a page in google?

Tags: seo

I've noticed that google sometimes show *thumbnail, total reviews, total pages, time needed, price, total matches, and even rating (with star images), etc*..

How can I let google display such **specific short info** and **small thumbnail image**?

[image: google results screenshot]

Comment: This question seems to be off-topic. It doesn't seem to be related to programmation, and should probably be posted to webmasters.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Pierre I think it might be related to something called "Open Graph", but I'm not sure..

Comment: FYI, OpenGraph is a Facebook API. Google (plus) one is called Microdata.

Comment: @Pierre, FYI, you've just gave me the answer I was looking for, post your comment as an answer plz

Comment: Done. That really was an unexpected answer =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for [Google's Microdata](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=176035), similar to Facebook's OpenGraph.